# Core Data exception thrown when adding object with relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, xcode5.1

I have been dealing with Core Data for weeks, and have not been able to solve several issues. It is a simple project, where I have 2 entities, with several attributes each. They have a one-to-many relationship, as there are several task lists.

I was able to save the task lists correctly, so when I start the app I can see the task lists I previously added. But when I am trying to add a task, I get an error stating:

2014-05-01 18:28:44.374 Simple Tasks[18627:60b] -[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d55170

This is the method that I am using to add a task:

```
    - (void) addTask: (id) taskInfo taskList: (TaskList *) newTaskList
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
        NSDictionary *myTask = (NSDictionary *) taskInfo;

        Task *newTask = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext: context];

        newTask.taskTitle = [myTask objectForKey:@"taskTitle"];
        newTask.taskDescription = [myTask objectForKey:@"taskDescription"];
        newTask.taskDueDate = [myTask objectForKey:@"taskDueDate"];
        newTask.taskDone = [myTask objectForKey:@"taskDone"];
        if (newTaskList)
        {
            [newTask addTaskListRelObject: newTaskList];
        }

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
```

And this is the line that is throwing the exception `[newTask addTaskListRelObject: newTaskList];`.

Also, this is what I am doing to retrieve the task list:

```
    NSDictionary *aTask = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:                                                         self.taskTitleField.text, @"taskTitle", self.taskDescriptionField.text, @"taskDescription", self.taskDueDateField.date, @"taskDueDate", nil];
    TaskList *myTaskList = [services searchTaskList: _taskListTitle]; //_taskListTitle is a string
    [services addTask: aTask taskList: myTaskList];
```

I have been reading some Core Data books, but I am still not sure what is going on.

The entities are called TaskList and Task. TaskList only has an attribute called title of type string. It has a relationship called tasks with destination Task and inverse taskListRel. "Task" has 3 attributes: taskDescription of type string, taskDueDate of type date and taskTitle of type string. It has a relationship called taskListRel with destination TaskList and inverse tasks.

Comment: Suggestion... Assuming your method `addTaskListRelObject:` is in the same class, try typing `[self addTaskListRelObject:newTaskList]`, alternatively if that method is in another class, type the name of that class (e.g. `Task`) instead of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like there is a problem with your .h files for each of the objects and potentially a mis-match between whats in them and what is in the coredata model.

I have also seen this when the auto generated accessors were not included in the .h as follows, suggest checking that this is present:
@interface Task (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void) addTaskListRelObject:(TaskList*)tasklist;
@end

Comment: The interface is present, but I just realized the parameter is an NSManagedObject instead of TaskList. I had not noticed, as the files were auto-generated by Xcode. I will do some testing and see what happens.